# How to use expand.grid to create all possible combinations between two columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, combinations, expand

I have a data frame with four columns and I need to expand it to include all the possible combinations between the values of two specific columns, without dropping the other columns.

A toy version of my dataset:

```
mydf <- tibble(ID = c(1:3), Group = rep("XX",3) ,Names1 = c("a","b","b"),Names2 = c("c","d","e"))

mydf
  ID Group Names1 Names2
1  1    XX      a      c
2  2    XX      b      d
3  3    XX      b      e
```

When I use `expand.grid()` on the the variables Names1 and Names2 I obtain the combinations that I want, but the other columns disappear. Other functions that perform similar operations like `expand()` and `complete()` didn't work because they drop the repeated values in Names1.

```
expand.grid(mydf$Names1, mydf$Names2)
  Var1 Var2
1    a    c
2    b    c
3    b    c
4    a    d
5    b    d
6    b    d
7    a    e
8    b    e
9    b    e
```

I have tried calling `expand.grid()` within `mutate()`, but the result is a replicated output from `expand.grid()`.

```
mydf %>% mutate(Combs = nest(expand.grid(Names1, Names2)))

A tibble: 3 x 5
     ID Group Names1 Names2 Combs$data      
  <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <list>          
1     1 XX    a      c      <tibble [9 x 2]>
2     2 XX    b      d      <tibble [9 x 2]>
3     3 XX    b      e      <tibble [9 x 2]>
```

I would like to obtain something like this, keeping the rest of the columns AND the replicated values in Names1:

```
   ID Group Names1 Names2
1   1   XX   a    c
2   2   XX   b    c
3   3   XX   b    c
4   1   XX   a    d
5   2   XX   b    d
6   3   XX   b    d
7   1   XX   a    e
8   2   XX   b    e
9   3   XX   b    e
```

I would prefer to do it with tidyverse, since I plan to use `group_by(Group)` on the complete dataset.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't get how you keep the other columns. In your desired result, do the `ID` and `Group` columns correspond do the original row of the `Names1` value or the `Names2` value? I think you have to pick one.

Comment: When `Names1 = a` and `Names2 = c` you have `ID = 1`; when `Names1 = a` and `Names2 = d` you have `ID = 1` and so on. It seems you are giving to each expanded row the `ID` corresponding to the variable `Names1` in `mydf`. What about `Group`? Is also getting its value from the corresponding to `Names1`?

Comment: Do you also want to include duplicates in the data? Values like b c, b d and be are repeated.

Comment: Yes, ID should follow Name1,  and Group doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want.  But it does deliver all the possible combinations. Maybe worth a look.

```
my_grid <- expand_grid(ID = c(1:3), Group = rep("XX",3) , 
                   Names1 = c("a","b","b"), 
                   Names2 = c("c","d","e") )
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

This is 3 years too late, but you could do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Your data
mydf <- tibble(ID = c(1:3), Group = rep("XX",3) ,Names1 = c("a","b","b"),Names2 = c("c","d","e"))

#make an empty column just with those combinations
empty_names <- mydf %>%
  expand(Names1, Names2)

#join on those columns
mydf %>%
  full_join(empty_names)
```

Note, this will give you NAs in the other columns for where the combination didn't originally exist, but that makes sense because R doesn't 'know' what to put there. Once merged, you could always use mutate() and case_when() to repopulate those columns based on whatever rules you have, such as all values of Group being XX.